# Should changelogs for stable versions include changes from preview versions?

Tags: versioning, changelog

I am maintaining a library that uses [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). The current stable release is 1.7.0, and I'm about to release version 2.0.0. In preparation for this fairly major upgrade, I've been uploading "release candidates" (2.0.0-rc1, 2.0.0-rc2, etc.). The changelog for each RC release includes all changes since the previous RC/stable release. My question is, **what should I include in the changelog for the final v2.0.0: everything since 1.7.0 or just the one or two minor things that changed since the last preview version?**

I suppose I could just not include the RCs in the changelog, but that doesn't really fit the [conventional changelog wisdom](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) of including every publicly released version. This library doesn't have very frequent updates either, so it's not like including preview versions would generate a lot of noise in the changelog (which I suspect is part of the reason why big projects like Babel or ESLint don't include every preview release in their changelogs). Anyway, I'm curious to know what other project maintainers recommend. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple rules (according to doc and nature):

1. **Every** *released* to public version **must** appear in changelog
2. Records for each version have to include notable changes since the previous version of product in changelog

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That makes sense, but isn't it kind of a poor user experience to have to look through multiple preview version changesets just to see "what's new in v2"?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 - from my POV - no. Also... i see a lot of well-established products, which follow this rule for a long time period. They have a strong reasoning, I suppose - a big set of small (structured by type of change inside) slices is better than one big list, *both* for eyes and automated parsers

Comment: Hm, yeah that's a good point. I guess if nothing else, none of the alternatives are better... You wouldn't want to exclude publicly released preview versions from the changelog, and you wouldn't want to duplicate changes from preview versions cause that's just confusing, ergo every release in the changelog must show the changes from the last release, even for major releases after a couple previews. Might be good to throw some of this follow-up into your answer, but for now I'll accept it. :) Thanks again!